# plone diazo with esi

Tags: plone, diazo, esi

Is that possible to avoid having the doctype, <html>, <head>, <body> added to a page when it is rendered with diazo?

My problem is that when varnish is loading content from an <esi:include src="/mypage"> tag, diazo adds the <!DOCTYPE, html head and body tags, to the loaded page. I would like to have only the html as it's given by "/mypage".

Thank you!